# Android notification showing some weird date in a corner

Tags: java, android

I'm not sure why when I'm showing notification there is some 1/4/70 date displaying in a top right corner? What is that? How do I get rid of it?

Code:

```
public static void showNotification(int id, String message, String title, String body)
    {
        int drawable = 0;
        switch (id)
        {
            case NOTIFICATION_NEW_MAIL:
                drawable = R.drawable.ic_notify_mail;
                break;

            case NOTIFICATION_AVAILABLE_TRIPS:
                drawable = R.drawable.ic_notify_trip;
                break;
        }

        NotificationManager notifyManager = (NotificationManager)MyApplication.Me.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Notification notification = new Notification(drawable, message, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 1000);
        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;

        Intent notificationIntent= new Intent(MyApplication.Me, MailListActivity.class);
        switch (id)
        {
            case NOTIFICATION_NEW_MAIL:
                notificationIntent = new Intent(MyApplication.Me, MailListActivity.class);
                break;

            case NOTIFICATION_AVAILABLE_TRIPS:
                notificationIntent = new Intent(MyApplication.Me, TripListActivity.class);
                break;
        }

        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(MyApplication.Me, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
        notification.setLatestEventInfo(MyApplication.Me, title, body, contentIntent);

        notifyManager.notify(id, notification);
    }
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That notification constructor is apparently deprecated, but anyway the last parameter in that constructor, when, should refer to in unix time what time the notification was created. SystemClock.getEllapsed time returns the amount of time since the system was booted http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/SystemClock.html. E.g. in your case, you're saying the notication was created very recently, but in unix time you're saying you're really close to 1970. Use System.getCurrentTimeMillis() instead.

EDIT: By close to 1970 I mean Unix time is measured in milliseconds from the start of 1970. So if you say 0ms you're saying Jan 1. If you pass in 86,400,000ms (ms in a day) you're saying Jan 2, 1970. By passing in the elapsed time since boot, it'll probably report you as a day or two from Jan 1, 1970. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time

Comment: Constructor deprecated, but I'm developing for API7 so it's only thing I have

Comment: Still then, use System.getCurrentTimeMillis() - that gives you the the correct time. SystemClock.getEllapsedTime, as I wrote, returns the amount of time since the system was booted. getCurrentTimeMillis() returns ms since Jan 1. 1970, and put the right time in the notifications box. Also, if this works could you accept this answer?

Comment: Answer is accepted already, but it's `System.currentTimeMillis();`, not `getCurrentTimeMillis()`

Comment: Sorry, I always make that mistake :(

Answer (score 0):

Whats that SystemClock thing? What's wrong with using System.currentTimeMillis() or System.nanoTime() ?

also, try to write a toClock() function that will convert it to a 12hr/24hr formatted time string. again, more on monday (sample code available) when i get back to the office.

Answer (score 0):

I think your means is that:

```
    Calendar canlender = Calendar.getInstance();
    canlender.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    canlender.add(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 1000);
    long TimeInMillised = canlender.getTimeInMillis();
    Notification notification = new Notification(drawable, message, TimeInMillised);
```

try it!